# could not convert string to float - object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with a dataframe in Python using Pandas and Jupyter Notebook, and my dataframe has Longitude and Latitude columns with values like '-23,4588'. Somehow, everytime I try to convert it to float, I get an error telling 'could not convert string to float'.

I tried to change the comma, tried to change the .csv column type to float, but nothing works.

A part of my code:

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\TEMP/ipykernel_12640/4061618161.py in <module>
----> 1 newocorr_sjc['Latitude'] = newocorr_sjc['Latitude'].astype(float)

c:\users\caique.fernandes\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5875         else:
   5876             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5877             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5878             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5879 

c:\users\caique.fernandes\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    629         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    630     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 631         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    632 
    633     def convert(

c:\users\caique.fernandes\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    425                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    426                 else:
--> 427                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    428             except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    429                 if not ignore_failures:

c:\users\caique.fernandes\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    671             vals1d = values.ravel()
    672             try:
--> 673                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    674             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    675                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

c:\users\caique.fernandes\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1095     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
   1096         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
-> 1097         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1098 
   1099     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-23,5327'```
````

Comment: -23,5327 should probably be -23.5327.  If you fix that, you will be able to covert it to type float.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `decimal=','` as argument of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
```

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(float)
     17       22       23
0  17.5 -23.5327 -46.8182
1  56.3 -23.4315 -47.1269
```

Comment: Tried both options but didn't work..

Comment: Can you share a sample of your csv file that doesn't work, please?

Comment: 30427;4284;2021;30/09/2021;30/09/2021;Rodovias;30;9;SETEMBRO;2021;2021.09;QUINTA;03:50:00;MADRUGADA;CARAPICUIBA;Metropolitana de São Paulo;SP 021;17,5;ESTADUAL;CONCESSIONÁRIA-ARTESP;CCR RODOANEL;PUBLICO;-23,5327;-46,8182;CAMINHAO;CONDUTOR;VIA;COLISAO;TRASEIRA;MASCULINO;50-54;54;CAMINHAO;Até 30 dias
120514;1766;2021;30/09/2021;30/09/2021;Rodovias;30;9;SETEMBRO;2021;2021.09;QUINTA;16:55:00;TARDE;ARACARIGUAMA;Sorocaba;SP 280;56,3;ESTADUAL;CONCESSIONÁRIA-ARTESP;VIAOESTE;PUBLICO;-23,4315;-47,1269;MOTOCICLETA;CONDUTOR;ESTABELECIMENTO DE SAUDE;COLISAO;TRASEIRA;MASCULINO;30-34;33;CAMINHAO;Até 30 dias

Comment: @Caiiqef. I updated my answer. Can you try it, please?

Comment: It shows me the only column with float type, and it's not long/lat column..

Comment: Share your file if you can?

Comment: I found some other options to resolve, like `df["Longitude"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Longitude"], errors='coerce')
df['Longitude'].sample(15)`

but it ended turning every value as `NaN`.

Here's my Github Repo(https://github.com/Caiiqef/acidentespublicos)

Comment: It seems you have some [invisible whitespace](https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+00A0) in your csv file.